# Sync local Database (sqlce) to remote sql server

Tags: sql-server, database, windows-phone-8, sql-server-ce

I am trying to built the following but i have no idea where to start.

I want to build a windowsphone 8 app which has a local database which contents can be edited by input fields. Now, once the user is finnished editing the database, and the app has saved this edits I want my app to check for a wifi connection. Once the app has confirmed this, the data from the local database has to be synced to a remote sql server.

Most of this is pretty plain simple but the question that i have is, how do i sync the local database with the one on the remote server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if you can use the Microsoft Sync Framework on windows Phone:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb736753.aspx

I had used it in desktop applications with good results.

Comment: No i have searched for that. The frameworks do not match, and its not usable for wp8

Comment: Well, maybe you could extend the framework to make it work in Windows Phone. It has well designed interfaces that you can implement with some effort.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sync/archive/2011/09/10/sync-framework-toolkit-now-available-for-download.aspx

Comment: I have decided to sync my database query by query into the server db. This because of two reasons. The one being the database is quite small. Second is that the complexity of other methods is to high.